# Javascript date picker multiple select

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a newbie in using JavaScript so I really don't know how to create a datepicker input field that will allowed multiple select. I did some searching but can't find a solution related to my case. Can you please help me? Thank you so much =)

**This is what I tried so far**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     function pageLoad(sender, args) {
         $(document).ready(function() {
             $("#<%=datepicker.ClientID %>").datepicker();
             $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").mouseover(function() {
                 $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
             });
         });
     }
     $(function() {
         $("#datepicker").datepicker();
     });
</script>

<input type = "text" id = "datepicker">
```

This is working in a single select only. What I want to do is to be able to select a multiple dates. Thanks!

Comment: did you try looking for jquery datepicker?

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal anything that will come up with a datepicker with multiple selection will do =)

Comment: what did you try so far? do you have any code yet? where here to help you fix a problem not to make your homework

Comment: You can try this link it might help you http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#example8

Comment: If you want to use JQuery (or learn what it is) you can check this calendar picker http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/.

Comment: Hello. @Stefan I edited my question above, And put the code I have so far. Thank you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [MultiDatePicker](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/) a jQuery plugin to solve your problem. Here is the demo code for using MultiDatePicker :

You just need to include the script and style needed for MultiDatePicker plugin :

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"/>
    <script src="http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"/>

   <input id="datePick" type="text"/>
   <script>
   $('#datePick').multiDatesPicker();
   </script>
```

Here is a live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3t4j9/)

If you find any bugs by using this plugin you can report them [here](https://github.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/issues)